# Why text-align:justify doesn't work with child block element

Tags: css

Just curious as to why text-align: justify doesn't work with a child block element?

Here is my html:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="inline-child"></div>
   <div class="inline-child"></div>
   <div class="inline-child"></div>
   <div class="block-child"></div>
</div>
```

Here is my css:

```
.parent {
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
    text-align: justify;
}

.inline-child {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 100px;
    width: 30%;
    background: red;
}

.block-child {
    /* display: inline-block;
    width: 100%; */
}
```

At this point, the code doesn't work, but if I make the block-child inline, justify works. Why?
http://jsfiddle.net/aLv8dp2z/1/

Comment: it's working : http://jsfiddle.net/aLv8dp2z/2/

Comment: it's working, just use center or left except justify, then you can understand easily.

Comment: jobayer, you dont understand, i want all elements to spread out evenly as in justfied, not left or center.

Comment: @bhojendra i want the inline-blocks to justify, not text within